# Keep all files of the same month + latest file before that, remove the rest

Tags: bash, shell, files, backup, timestamps

I want a shell script that keep all file with time-stamp of the same month as the current time + the latest file before that, and delete the rest of the files in the directory.

All filename stored in the directory are structured as `name$timestamp.extension` where

```
timestamp=`date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`
```

So, this means that if there is the following file in the directory:

```
name161214-082211.gz
name161202-082211.gz
name161020-082211.gz
name161003-082211.gz
name161001-082211.gz
```

The remaining file in the directory after the execution of this code will be:

```
name161214-082211.gz
name161202-082211.gz
name161020-082211.gz
```

PS. Extremely new to shell. Would love to not only have a working code, but also to learn. So, if you would be so kind, please explain the code as well. Thank you!

Comment: Can we rely on the mtime of the files and not just the filenames?

Comment: @jayhendren I wish I could use this: 
find filename -mtime +31 -type f -delete
But, there are months that are 28, 30, 31 days as well. So, this method would not be inclusive enough keep "all files of the same month as the current time" + "the latest file before that".

Comment: that's ok, i was just wondering if the mtime is safe to key off of or if you can only use the name of the file to determine which ones to delete.

Comment: @jayhendren I see what you mean. mtime is safe.

Comment: just a off-topic hint: you might want to use 'backintime' as backup program which does what you require with default unix tools and data deduplication of your backups

Comment: @Jaleks Thanks, Jaleks. I'll keep that tool in mind. Just can't switch system right now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `zsh` you could do something like

```
# get current date (YYMM) in a variable 
crd=$(date "+%y%m")
# use a function to extract the 13 chars that make up the timestamp
dtts() REPLY=${${REPLY%%.*}: -13}
# sort file names by the timestamp in descending order, exclude the ones with the
# same YYMM as the current date and set the remaining file names as arguments
set -- *(.O+dtts^e_'[[ "${${REPLY%%.*}: -13:4}" == "$crd" ]]'_)
# remove the first item from the list (i.e. the last one before current month)
shift
# print the remaining file names
print -rl -- "$@"
```

This uses parameter expansion and [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation):
it first selects regular files (.) sorts in descending order (`O`) by the timestamp using the `dtts` function, then the negated `e`string `^e_'[[ "${${REPLY%%.*}: -13:4}" == "$crd" ]]'_` deselects files if the timestamp matches current year and month (i.e. if the expression inside quotes returns true); `shift` then removes the first item from the list (since the names were sorted in descending order that would be the latest timestamp before current month)
Replace `print -rl` with `rm` if you're happy with the result.

Comment: `zsh` code was run on terminal platform. The function to extract 13 chars has an unexpected token - precisely at `: -13`

Comment: @Perth - my post is pretty clear... it says _with **zsh**_. What you did was to open a terminal and simply run the code (and your shell is `bash` **not** `zsh`) hence the error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'REPLY=${${REPLY%%.*}: -13}'`

Comment: I see. So, bash and zsh cannot work together -Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Perth - no, your either run one or the other. Just install `zsh` (if not already installed on your system) and then open a terminal and execute `zsh` and _then_ my code...

Answer (score 0):

a bash solution would be:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

keep=$(date '+%y%m')
rm `find . -name "name*" -and -not -name "name$keep*" | sort | head -n-1`
```

- set variable $keep to current year (2-digit) and month.
- remove the result of the backticks-enclosed code which is
- 1. find all filenames in current directory (and subdirectories) that start with "name" and don't start with "name$keep"
- 2. sort the results
- 3. remove last line

however, i would not use a pure shell script in such cases, because the code might get complicated (and thus less maintainable) very fast.

you could use perl (or python) instead:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

# collect the names of all files older than current month.
# we assume that there are no files from future.
my $keep_date = strftime("%y%m", localtime);
my @files = sort grep {!/^name$keep_date/} glob "*.gz";

# the newest file from the collected files shall not be deleted
pop @files; 

# delete all collected files
map {unlink} @files;
```

or directly from the command line:

```
perl -We 'use POSIX qw(strftime); my $keep_date = strftime("%y%m", localtime); my @files = sort grep {!/^name$keep/} glob "*.gz"; pop @files; map {unlink} @files;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `zsh` approach:

```
# today as YYMMDD using prompt expansion
now=${(%):-%D{%y%m%d}}

# construct patterns
month="name<$now[1,4]01-$now>-<->.gz" all="name<-$now>-<->.gz"

# perform globbing (expand patterns to list of matching files)
month=($~month(N))                    all=($~all)
() (rm -f -- $argv[1,-2]) ${all:|month}
```

That's using `${all:|month}` array subtraction where the `$all` array is built from the list of files in the *any date to now* range and `$month` built from the list of files in the *first day of month to now* range.