# Extract highest day from time-stamp date within a filename

Tags: bash, shell, files, sort, timestamps

filename is structured as `name$timestamp.extension` where:

```
timestamp=`date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`
```

So, if there are following files in a directory:

```
name161214-082211.gz
name161202-082211.gz
name161220-082211.gz
name161203-082211.gz
name161201-082211.gz
```

With the execution of the code/script from your answer, the value `20` should be stored in the variable `highest_day`

```
highest_day = 20
```

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so far? It's not nice simply ask to write a script for you.

Comment: Are all the files from the same month (I'm presuming "yes")? If that's the case you should be able to get the correct *file* with only `ls` and `tail`. Getting the "day" component of the filename is slightly trickier, but do-able. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @andreatsh Sorry to hear that you see it that way. I can understand why. I am trying to work out [this problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330443/keep-all-files-of-the-same-month-latest-file-before-that-remove-the-rest), and the question that you see before you right here is where I got stuck. So, I wrote the question with a  pseudo code that shows only the input and the output. And, allow the answerers enough room to answer in their most effective way, which, in effect, allows me to learn from it.

Comment: @don_crissti You got me. I have confidence in my pseudo code. Albeit, it is certainly a long winded way - using only my limited knowledge of what shell language can do. Would really love to see and understand how an expert would do it.

Comment: @JohnN Your attention to detail is very admirable. Quick answer is no. I didn't want to make the question too complex. If I can see how you would extract just the day, I would know how to extract just the timestamp (without the hours, minutes and second), then use if else statements to classify the month, and lastly the date. So, to answer your second question, I am stuck precisely on how to get just the day. Coming up with the pseudo code was easy. For me, to fit that logic into convention code is what's hard. I'll certainly look more into `tail`. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This'll pull out the DD-part (of name-YYMMDD-XXXXX.tar.gz): `sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*[0-9]{4}([0-9]{2}).*/\1/'` on GNU (replace -r with -E for BSD sed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using file timestamps it gets a little clunky but this is one way it can be done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

re="name([0-9]{6})-([0-9]{6})\.gz"
re2="([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})"

for file in *.gz
do
    if [[ "$file" =~ $re ]]
    then
        # BASH_REMATCH[n] on filename where n:
        # [1] is date ie. 161202
        # [2] is time ie. 082211
        date=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

        # BASH_REMATCH[n] on date string where n:
        # [1] is year ie. 16
        # [2] is month ie. 12
        # [3] is day ie. 02
        [[ $date =~ $re2 ]] && day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

        # Keep max day value
        [[ $day > $highest_day ]] && highest_day=$day
    fi
done

echo $highest_day
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this..

```
highest_day= $(for i in *.gz; do echo ${i:8:2}; done | sort -n | tail -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list of files is inside a file, something like:

```
$ cd dir
$ ls -1 * >infile
```

This pipe gets the job done:

```
$ sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)-.*/\1/' infile | sort -r | head -n1 | cut -c 5-6
20
```